# SQL query to select previous 14 months where add amount '0' if any month is missing

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have create this query to select the date, amount for previous 14 months, In this case the month is missing if no record is present for that month, Please suggest me a solution to add zero and month if that paticular month is missing.

```
SELECT dtSubscriptionRenewalDate, 
DATE_FORMAT(dtSubscriptionRenewalDate, "%b %Y") AS month,     
SUM(intPaymentAmount) as total 
FROM `tbl_pi_payment` 
WHERE strCurrencyCode = 'USD' 
and dtSubscriptionRenewalDate <= NOW() 
and dtSubscriptionRenewalDate >= Date_add(Now(),interval - 14 month) 
group by month  
ORDER BY `tbl_pi_payment`.`dtSubscriptionRenewalDate`  ASC;
```

[image]

You can view from the results, That NOv 2018 is missing.

Comment: You have data for Nov 2018?

Comment: No, There are no records in the table for NOV 2018

Comment: That case how you expect row for Nov 2018 should be there in the output? If you need all available month between your start and end date, either you have to use a calendar table Or you can generate the month list in another query and then join with your main query.

Comment: Please can you let me know how is that done?

Comment: Create a tally table of months and left join your query.

Comment: MySQL or Mariadb? And what version?

Comment: Its MySQL. version 5.6.45

Comment: your `SELECT dtSubscriptionRenewalDate` is going to give an arbitrary renewal date from the data for each month.  you probably want to use min() or max().

Comment: your `dtSubscriptionRenewalDate >=` where condition, if run today, would find some records for October 2018, but not include those for Oct 1-Oct 5 (those slightly more than 14 months ago).  Is that what you want?  or do you want to select data for entire months (except for the current month)?

Comment: I want to select the entire month except the current month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an ad-hoc table with select/union of the possible months, then left join your table from that, selecting only the records for the given month.  For convenience, compute the date range from the number of months ago (but you could just use the more complicated expressions for start date and end date in the join instead).

```
select
    min(dtSubscriptionRenewalDate) as min_renewal_date,
    date_format(date_sub(now(), interval months_ago month), "%b %Y") as month,
    coalesce(sum(intPaymentAmount),0) as total
from (
    select
        months_ago,
        date(date_format(date_sub(now(), interval months_ago month), "%Y-%m-01")) start_date,
        date(date_format(date_sub(now(), interval months_ago-1 month), "%Y-%m-01")) end_date
    from (select 0 months_ago union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10 union select 11 union select 12 union select 13 union select 14 order by months_ago) months_ago
) date_range
left join tbl_pi_payment on
    dtSubscriptionRenewalDate >= start_date and
    dtSubscriptionRenewalDate < end_date and
    dtSubscriptionRenewalDate <= now() and
    strCurrencyCode = 'USD'
group by months_ago desc;
```

This will report NULL as the renewal date for months with no records, and the minimum renewal date found for months that do have records.  Not sure what exactly you want there.

Answer (score 0):

You may first generate the months and year and then can left join that with your query -

```
SELECT dtSubscriptionRenewalDate, 
DATE_FORMAT(dtSubscriptionRenewalDate, "%b %Y") AS month,     
SUM(intPaymentAmount) as total 
FROM (SELECT 'January' AS months
      UNION 
      SELECT 'February'
      UNION 
      SELECT 'March'
      UNION 
      SELECT 'April'
      UNION 
      SELECT 'May'
      UNION 
      SELECT 'June'
      UNION 
      SELECT 'July'
      UNION 
      SELECT 'August'
      UNION 
      SELECT 'September'
      UNION 
      SELECT 'October'
      UNION 
      SELECT 'November'
      UNION 
      SELECT 'December') month
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 2018 AS years
            UNION
            SELECT 2019
            UNION 
            SELECT 2020) year
LEFT JOIN `tbl_pi_payment` tp ON YEAR(tp.dtSubscriptionRenewalDate) = year.years
                              AND MONTH(tp.dtSubscriptionRenewalDate) = month.months
WHERE strCurrencyCode = 'USD' 
and dtSubscriptionRenewalDate <= NOW() 
and dtSubscriptionRenewalDate >= Date_add(Now(),interval - 14 month) 
group by month  
ORDER BY `tbl_pi_payment`.`dtSubscriptionRenewalDate` ASC;
```

Comment: that isn't going to order the months with no data correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try generating calendar date and make the `JOIN`

```
CREATE TABLE daterange (dte DATE); 

SET @counter := 15;
WHILE (@counter < 0) DO 
    INSERT daterange VALUES (SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL @counter:=@counter - 1 Month));
END WHILE;


SELECT dtSubscriptionRenewalDate, DATE_FORMAT(dte, "%b %Y") AS month, SUM(intPaymentAmount) as total 
FROM daterange D LEFT JOIN `tbl_pi_payment` T ON T.DATE_FORMAT(dtSubscriptionRenewalDate, "%b %Y") = D.DATE_FORMAT(dte , "%b %Y")
WHERE strCurrencyCode = 'USD' and dtSubscriptionRenewalDate <= NOW() and dtSubscriptionRenewalDate >= Date_add(Now(),interval - 14 month) 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dte, "%b %Y") 
ORDER BY `tbl_pi_payment`.`dtSubscriptionRenewalDate`  ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle like this:

```
SELECT md.month AS month,     
SUM(intPaymentAmount) as total 
FROM `tbl_pi_payment` ,
(select add_month(trunc(sysdate,'MM')-level) month from dual connect by level <15) md
WHERE strCurrencyCode = 'USD' 
trunc(dtSubscriptionRenewalDate,'MM')(+)=md.month
group by md.month
ORDER BY md.month  ASC;
```